# Convert spwd.db to master.passwd, specify paths

Tags: freebsd

I need to produce master.passwd given spwd.db and pwd.db, like one can do with `pwd_mkdb -p`. However, I need to specify both input and output paths.

So, given `somesuch/spwd.db` and `somesuch/pwd.db`, I want to produce `somesuch/master.passwd`.

I have naively tried something along the lines of `pwd_mkdb -p -d somesuch/ somesuch/spwd.db` with no success ("Inappropriate file type or format").

Comment: Should this be moved to Server Fault or Linux & Unix?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot produce `master.passwd` from `spwd.db` with pwd_mkdb.
The `-p` option only generates a `/etc/passwd` file, which does *not* contain the password hashes!

The proper procedure is to restore `master.passwd` from your backups. If you don't have those, this is a good example of why you *should* have backups of all your configuration data!

Check `/var/backups` for backup copies of `master.passwd`.

If there are no backups to be found, you'll have to reconstitute `master.passwd` from the contents of `spwd.db`. The files `/etc/pwd.db` and `/etc/spwd.db` are Berkeley Database files:

```
file /etc/pwd.db
/etc/pwd.db: Berkeley DB 1.85 (Hash, version 2, native byte-order)
```

If you want to read these databases, you can e.g. use the `db4_dump185` program from `/usr/ports/databases/db4`.

When reading the files in this way, note the following info from the source code from `/usr/src/usr.sbin/pwd_mkdb/pwd_mkdb.c`:

```
    /*
     * The databases actually contain three copies of the original data.
     * Each password file entry is converted into a rough approximation
     * of a ``struct passwd'', with the strings placed inline.  This
     * object is then stored as the data for three separate keys.  The
     * first key * is the pw_name field prepended by the _PW_KEYBYNAME
     * character.  The second key is the pw_uid field prepended by the
     * _PW_KEYBYUID character.  The third key is the line number in the
     * original file prepended by the _PW_KEYBYNUM character.  (The special
     * characters are prepended to ensure that the keys do not collide.)
     */
```

Read the aforementioned source code to see how the lines are stored in the hashed database:

```
#define COMPACT(e)      t = e; while ((*p++ = *t++));
#define SCALAR(e)       store = htonl((uint32_t)(e));      \
                        memmove(p, &store, sizeof(store)); \
                        p += sizeof(store);
#define LSCALAR(e)      store = HTOL((uint32_t)(e));       \
                        memmove(p, &store, sizeof(store)); \
                        p += sizeof(store);
#define HTOL(e)         (openinfo.lorder == BYTE_ORDER ? \
                        (uint32_t)(e) : \
                        bswap32((uint32_t)(e)))
```

and

```
                    /* Create secure data. */
                    p = sbuf;
                    COMPACT(pwd.pw_name);
                    COMPACT(pwd.pw_passwd);
                    SCALAR(pwd.pw_uid);
                    SCALAR(pwd.pw_gid);
                    SCALAR(pwd.pw_change);
                    COMPACT(pwd.pw_class);
                    COMPACT(pwd.pw_gecos);
                    COMPACT(pwd.pw_dir);
                    COMPACT(pwd.pw_shell);
                    SCALAR(pwd.pw_expire);
                    SCALAR(pwd.pw_fields);
                    sdata.size = p - sbuf;
```

Comment: I up-voted this answer because the tail end about the db4 was useful. The lecture about backups was tedious and was generally why FreeBSD has bled users for ages. And I'm an off and on user since the late 90s. Lots of reasons to want to restore master.passwd from the .db files - auditing for one.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did want to audit a system to confirm that the `/etc/spwd.db` file was what `/etc/master.passwd` says it was, I wrote the following. I suspect it's not complete but it was enough for my circumstances. If you think something is missing - have the `default:` branch of the `switch` emit some debug info - it will at the very least complain about the version entry I'm ignoring.

Best of luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <db.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/endian.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pwd.h>

#define _PW_VERSION_MASK    '\xF0'
#define _PW_VERSIONED(x, v) ((unsigned char)(((x) & 0xCF) | ((v)<<4)))
#define _PW_KEYBYNAME       '\x31'  /* stored by name */
#define _PW_KEYBYNUM        '\x32'  /* stored by entry in the "file" */
#define _PW_KEYBYUID        '\x33'  /* stored by uid */
#define _PW_KEYYPENABLED    '\x34'  /* YP is enabled */
#define _PW_KEYYPBYNUM      '\x35'  /* special +@netgroup entries */
#define _NPW_KEYBYNAME      '\x41'  /* stored by name */
#define _NPW_KEYBYNUM       '\x42'  /* stored by entry in the "file" */
#define _NPW_KEYBYUID       '\x43'  /* stored by uid */
#define _NPW_KEYYPENABLED   '\x44'  /* YP is enabled */
#define _NPW_KEYYPBYNUM     '\x45'  /* special +@netgroup entries */
#define _PWD_VERSION_KEY    "\xFF" "VERSION"


static HASHINFO openinfo = {
  4096,           /* bsize */
  32,             /* ffactor */
  256,            /* nelem */
  2048 * 1024,    /* cachesize */
  NULL,           /* hash() */
  BIG_ENDIAN      /* lorder */
};

void die(char *reason) {
  printf("FATAL: %s\n", reason? reason: strerror(errno));
  exit(1);
}

#define UNCOMPACT(field, name) \
  plen = strlen(p); \
  if (i + plen > len) die("data malformed"); \
  field = p; \
  i += plen + 1; \
  p += plen + 1
#define UNSCALAR(field) \
  if (i + sizeof(uint32_t) > len) die("data malformed"); \
  field = (*unscalar_func)(*(uint32_t *)p); \
  i += sizeof(uint32_t); \
  p += sizeof(uint32_t)

uint32_t uint32_t_noop(uint32_t data) {
  return data;
}

void print_pwd(uint32_t (*unscalar_func)(uint32_t), size_t len, char *data) {
  struct passwd pwd;
  size_t plen, i = 0;
  char *p;

  p = data;
  UNCOMPACT(pwd.pw_name, "pwd.pw_name");
  UNCOMPACT(pwd.pw_passwd, "pwd.pw_passwd");
  UNSCALAR(pwd.pw_uid);
  UNSCALAR(pwd.pw_gid);
  UNSCALAR(pwd.pw_change);
  UNCOMPACT(pwd.pw_class, "pwd.pw_class");
  UNCOMPACT(pwd.pw_gecos, "pwd.pw_gecos");
  UNCOMPACT(pwd.pw_dir, "pwd.pw_dir");
  UNCOMPACT(pwd.pw_shell, "pwd.pw_shell");
  UNSCALAR(pwd.pw_expire);
  UNSCALAR(pwd.pw_fields);

  printf("%s:%s:" "%d:%d:" "%s:" "%ld:%ld:" "%s:%s:%s\n",
         pwd.pw_name, pwd.pw_passwd,
         pwd.pw_uid, pwd.pw_gid,
         pwd.pw_class,
         pwd.pw_change, pwd.pw_expire,
         pwd.pw_gecos, pwd.pw_dir, pwd.pw_shell);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  DB *db;
  DBT key, data;
  int rc;

  db = dbopen(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0777, DB_HASH, &openinfo);


  for (;;) {
    rc = db->seq(db, &key, &data, R_NEXT);
    if (rc == -1) die("R_NEXT");
    if (rc == 1) break;

    // Overdone - letting sort -u reduce this later.
    switch (*(char *)key.data) {
      case _PW_KEYBYNAME:
      case _PW_KEYBYNUM:
      case _PW_KEYBYUID:
        print_pwd(uint32_t_noop, data.size, (char *)data.data);
        break;   ;;
      case _NPW_KEYBYNAME:
      case _NPW_KEYBYNUM:
      case _NPW_KEYBYUID:
        print_pwd(ntohl, data.size, (char *)data.data);
        break;   ;;
      default:
        break;   ;;

    }
  }
}
```